# Seletor CSS ou JS

Tags: html, css

Tenho um parágrafo sem id que preciso estilizar. A estilização só pode ocorrer para esse parágrafo. Exemplo:

```
<p>Conteúdo</p>
```

Então quero aplicar CSS somente para ele.

```
seletor {estilo;}
```

Obs.: Eu não posso adicionar um id no "p".

Comment: Isso é um problema de programação ou um caso real? quantos `<p>` tens na página e qual é a estrutura do HTML à volta?

Comment: É como se fosse uma assinatura. Aparece em várias páginas. Eu pensei em usar o seletor por ordem de tag, tipo "div p a {foo;}", mas não dá, porque aparece em estruturas diferentes.

Comment: E é somente `<p>` sem nenhum atributo?

Comment: Tem um text-align:center, mas é muito vago.

Comment: Coloca por favor o HTML desse p, seu conteúdo e possiveis elementos superiores/ancestrais que sejam sempre iguais.

Comment: acho que sempre tem div p

Comment: Acho que vais ficar sem resposta pois não há detalhes para poder responder...

Comment: Eu vou tentar com jQuery. Achei que existia uma maneira de selecionar pelo conteúdo de dentro do HTML e usar CSS. Valeu!

Comment: Pois, talvez, mas nem esse conteúdo partilhaste connosco por isso não podemos adivinhar.

Comment: Eu não achei que fosse relevante. Segue o conteúdo: <p>Powered by <a href="www.whmcs.com">WHMCompleteSolution</a>.</p>

Comment: Se é o caso de adicionar um estilo para todos os "<p>" que forem assinatura, porque não coloca uma "class" neles?

Comment: E qual o problema de criar uma classe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para estilizar com JavaScript podes selecionar o a ancora com `[href="www.whmcs.com"]`.

Exemplo:

```js
var a = document.querySelector('[href="www.whmcs.com"]');
var p = a.parentElement;

p.style.backgroundColor = '#ddf';
p.style.padding = '5px';
```

```html
<p>Algo...</p>
<p>Powered by <a href="www.whmcs.com">WHMCompleteSolution</a>.</p> 
<p>Algo...</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

tente pegar o seletor pai desse p por exemplo:

```
#meu_id p{}
```

Ou talvez pegar por índice

```
p:nth-child(1){}
```

Comment: a estrutura do html muda, dependendo da página.

Comment: Eu achei que poderia selecionar pelo innerHTML.

Comment: tem como postar mais ou menos como está ficando seu html?

Comment: Talvez eu deveria ter explicado antes: eu uso o WHMCS, e não consigo remover a assinatura dele. Isso está me incomodando. Já li um monte de tutoriais, mas não funciona. Então pensei em remover com CSS.

Comment: a se for o caso tenta usar js mesmo, pega o container onde o P está dentro e verifica os childNodes, tenta pegar o p necessário por childNode, caso esteja usando jQuery vc pode tentar pegar o p de acordo com o texto que está dentro do p utilizando contains. Bom essas são minhas ideias espero que tenha ajudado, boa sorte!!

Comment: Vou pesquisar sobre isso no jQuery. É que queria fazer com CSS. Mas se não der vai jQuery mesmo. Valeu cara!

Answer (score 0):

Se este paragrafo é único não vejo mal algum em usar simplesmente **uma classe**, afinal é *pra isto mesmo que elas existem*, não tem motivo pra criar um seletor complexo ou usar JavaScript, basta fazer algo como:

```css
.powerdby {
    color: #f00; /* é apenas um exemplo */
}
```

```html
<p>Oi</p>

<p class="powerdby">
Powered by <a href="www.whmcs.com">WHMCompleteSolution</a>.
</p>

<p>Tchau</p>
```

**Nota:** para estilizar links é necessário aplicar um seletor como `.poweredby a { ... }`, pois cores e sublinhados não são afetados pela herança, nem mesmo com `!important`

Comment: Eu não achei o arquivo que contem o html. Só achei o arquivo de CSS que é mais fácil de encontrar. Por isso teria que selecionar de forma alternativa.

Comment: @genesisWP não entendi

Comment: Para eu adicionar uma class no <p> preciso editar o arquivo que contém a informação. Eu simplesmente não sei onde está esse arquivo.

Comment: @genesisWP isso é no mínimo estranho, vc não sabe ou não entende a estrutura do servidor?

Comment: É o WHMCS. Eu realmente não entendo de WHMCS.

Comment: @genesisWP entendo, vou dar uma olhada nisto e te aviso